# Generating Function for 2-Associated Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, generating-functions

I am looking for a paper which explicitly defines a power series for 2-associated Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind.  The paper defines the generating function as follows:
Let $S_2(n,k)=b(n,k)$ be the 2 associated Stirling Numbers of the second kind.  Then
$$\sum_{k,n\ge1}b(n,k)u^k\frac{t^n}{n!}=\exp{(u\exp{(1-Q(2,t)}})$$
where $Q(2,t)=\frac{\Gamma(2,t)}{\Gamma(2)}$
I found the paper, and never wrote down the author or journal.  Any help would be amazing!

EDIT:  I am not having much luck with help here.  Perhaps, instead of finding the actual article itself, outside of just google searching (which is how i found it, I just can't seem to enter the same search and have the same luck now), what might be some strategies to finding such an article?  I don't know the author, I don't know the publication, I only know subject matter.  I am a first year grad student, and am not accustomed to finding mathematical journal articles except Googling and praying...

Comment: why are not you searching into your history of web search?

Comment: I did but I've done so much searching for articles and stuff regarding these numbers that it has just become difficult.  At this point, I don't know when it was I even found it or where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note:* I think @jayakrishnan provides an interesting reference about the *2-associated Stirling Numbers of the second kind* from F.T.Howard.

> Here's another paper which looks promising. The idea is, that even if it's *not exactly*  the article you have in mind the formulae of $S_2(n,k)$ you will find in the referred papers could be nevertheless valuable and a proper substitute for the formulae you want to find.
>
> - So you might find [Some Properties of Associated Stirling Numbers (2008)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=DCDDF0FAA885DC051D7B02BB1B206870?doi=10.1.1.188.9846&rep=rep1&type=pdf) from *Feng-Zhen Zhao* interesting.

It presents (besides other numbers) *r-associated Stirling numbers of the second kind* $S_r(n,k)$:
$$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}S_r(n,k)\frac{t^n}{n!}
=\frac{1}{k!}\left(e^t-\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}\frac{t^j}{j!}\right)^k$$ and you will find using the definition 
$$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}S_2(n,k)\frac{t^n}{n!}
=\frac{(e^t-1-t)^k}{k!}$$
some interesting identities about $S_2(n,k)$. Maybe a *recurrence formula* (2.2) of $S_2(n,k)$ with the help of Bernoulli numbers is useful:

$$\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n+k-1}{j}S_2(n-j+k,k)B_j=(n+k-1)S_2(n+k-2,k-1)\qquad k\geq 2$$

or some *asymptotic expansions* of $S_2(n,k)$ at the end of the paper.

---

**Added 2014-12-03:** With respect to the comment of @Eleven-Eleven I have added another hint which could give some more insights.

Regarding *associated Stirling numbers of the second kind* you can find in [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf) from *Flajolet* and *Sedgewick* **interesting concepts** and some nice examples. You may have a look at *chapter II: Labelled Structures and Exponential Generating Functions*.

You can read in *Section II.3*: *Surjections, set partitions, and words*:

> - Example II.4 (13) (p. 124):  *Stirling numbers of the second kind*

The Stirling numbers of the second kind, $S_n^{(k)}$, denoting the number of ways of partitioning the set $[1..n]$ into $k$ disjoint and non-empty equivalence classes (called *blocks*) can be *modelled by the symbolic structure*:

$$S^{(k)}=\text{SET}_k\left(\text{SET}_{\leq 1}(\mathcal{Z})\right)$$

which **directly translates** into the exponential generating function (EGF) for $S_n^{(k)}$

$$S^{(k)}(z)=\sum_{n\geq k}S_n^{(k)}\frac{z^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{k!}\left(e^z-1\right)^k$$

> - Example II.6: *Smallest and largest blocks in set partitions*.

Let $e_b(z)$ denote the *truncated exponential function*:

$$e_b(z) := 1+\frac{z}{1!}+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{z^b}{b!}$$

The EGFs $S^{(\leq b)}(z)$ and $S^{(>b)}(z)$ with

$$S^{(\leq b)}(z)=\exp\left(e_b(z)-1\right)\qquad \qquad S^{(>b)}(z)=\exp\left(e^z-e_b(z)\right)$$

correspond to partitions with all blocks of size $\leq b$ and all blocks of size $>b$, respectively.

> - Example II.7: The EGF of *partitions without singleton parts* is

$$e^{e^z-1-z}$$

> - Example II.8: *Restricted words*. The EGF of words over an alphabet of cardinality $k$ containing each letter *at most $b$ times*, and that of words containing each letter *more* than $b$ times are

$$\mathcal{W}^{(\leq b)}(z)=e_b(z)^k,\qquad \qquad\mathcal{W}^{(> b)}(z)=\left(e^z-e_b(z)\right)^k$$

... and some more examples

---

*Note:* Observe, that setting $b=1$ results in the 2-associated Stirling numbers of the second kind

$$S_2(n,k)=\frac{1}{k!}\left(e(z)-e_b(z)\right)^k$$

Comment: I've seen a lot of Howard's papers so I am familiar with his work and there are some tidbits like the things you've mentioned above.  The good news is that I wrote the formula down in the question area so i have it, I just don't know how it was derived and am not 100% sure it's exact.  Thank you for the help though.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: I've added some new info which could be interesting for you. It could provide you with *new ways* to derive generating functions! Best regards,

Comment: Now that is good stuff.  Similar in structure and good for use in my research.  Thank you @Markus Scheuer

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: Great to see it's useful! Good speed! :-)

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: Thanks for granting the bounty! Regards,

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this will be helpful or not. You might want to check out the following link, particularly, the reference list in the end : 
http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/18-4/howard.pdf

Comment: Interesting paper! +1